# TextBox's IsMouseOver trigger only works before the control's IsFocused trigger is triggered

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpf-controls

## Problem & Intents

I am trying to create a `TextBox` style that with a drop shadow. The drop shadow opacity should increase slightly when the mouse is over, then increase even more when the `TextBox` is focused.

I currently have two triggers set up inside a TextBox style: an `IsMouseOver` trigger and an `IsFocused` trigger. Both of these work fine independently; however, when they are put together, some problems arise. The `IsMouseOver` only works before the `IsFocused` trigger is triggered. Afterwards, `IsMouseOver` no longer works.

## Code

```html
<Style TargetType="TextBox">
    <Style.Resources>
        <Storyboard x:Key="ShowShadow">
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Effect).Opacity">
                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.1" Value="0.5"/>
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        </Storyboard>
        <Storyboard x:Key="HideShadow">
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Effect).Opacity">
                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.1" Value="0.3"/>
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        </Storyboard>
        <Storyboard x:Key="MaxShadow">
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Effect).Opacity">
                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.1" Value="0.7"/>
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        </Storyboard>
    </Style.Resources>

    <Setter Property="Effect">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="1" BlurRadius="6" Opacity="0.3"></DropShadowEffect>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>

    <!-- other styles such as font, color etc removed -->

    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" x:Name="Bd" BorderThickness="0" CornerRadius="4" BorderBrush="{StaticResource BorderColorBrush}">
                    <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"  x:Name="PART_ContentHost" />
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>

    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Trigger.EnterActions>
                <BeginStoryboard
                    Storyboard="{StaticResource ShowShadow}"/>
            </Trigger.EnterActions>
            <Trigger.ExitActions>
                <BeginStoryboard
                    Storyboard="{StaticResource HideShadow}"/>
            </Trigger.ExitActions>
        </Trigger>

        <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
            <Trigger.EnterActions>
                <BeginStoryboard
                    Storyboard="{StaticResource MaxShadow}"/>
            </Trigger.EnterActions>
            <Trigger.ExitActions>
                <BeginStoryboard
                    Storyboard="{StaticResource HideShadow}"/>
            </Trigger.ExitActions>
        </Trigger>

    </Style.Triggers>

</Style>
```

## Expected vs Actual Behavior

### Expected

1. The user hovers over the TextBox and the drop shadow's opacity increases slightly to the correct value.
2. The user clicks on the TextBox to type in it and the drop shadow's opacity increases even further to the correct value.
3. The user clicks elsewhere and the TextBox loses focus. The opacity returns to its original value.
4. The user hovers over the TextBox and the drop shadow's opacity increases slightly to the correct value.
5. The user clicks on the TextBox to type in it and the drop shadow's opacity increases even further to the correct value.

### Actual

1. The user hovers over the TextBox and the drop shadow's opacity increases slightly to the correct value.
2. The user clicks on the TextBox to type in it and the drop shadow's opacity increases even further to the correct value.
3. The user clicks elsewhere and the TextBox loses focus. The opacity returns to its original value.
4. The user hovers over the TextBox again - **nothing happens.**
5. The user clicks on the TextBox - the opacity increases to the correct value.

What I've tried

- Using the `IsKeyboardFocused` trigger instead of `IsFocused`
- Swapping the order of the two triggers
- This actually created more problems - the `IsFocused` trigger didn't work at all.

## Video of the problem

https://youtu.be/LT7fWA6uRLo

Do note that I made it so when you click on the main `Window`, it will focus on the main `Grid`. This is how the TextBox loses its focus when I click on the empty space.

Answer (score 0):

There is one problem inherent in your design: If the TextBox is focused and the mouse is moved away, the drop shadow opacity will return to normal.

Apart from that, try this:

```
<Style.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="TextBox.MouseEnter">
        <EventTrigger.Actions>
            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource ShowShadow}"/>
        </EventTrigger.Actions>
    </EventTrigger>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="TextBox.MouseLeave">
        <EventTrigger.Actions>
            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource HideShadow}"/>
        </EventTrigger.Actions>
    </EventTrigger>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="TextBox.GotFocus">
        <EventTrigger.Actions>
            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource MaxShadow}"/>
        </EventTrigger.Actions>
    </EventTrigger>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="TextBox.LostFocus">
        <EventTrigger.Actions>
            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource HideShadow}"/>
        </EventTrigger.Actions>
    </EventTrigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```

Comment: I tried something similar to this earlier. It kind of worked, but I don't want the MouseLeave event to fire when the TextBox is focused. I'll give your code a shot tomorrow. Also, I believe the problem you stated in your answer isn't connected to the problem stated in my question.